# How to get customer information after paypal transaction?

Tags: cakephp, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to get the customer's address, name and any information that they enter on the paypal side so I can create a customer account with order history. I am currently using web payments standard for the simplicity.

How do I get that information from paypal after the user is sent back to my confirmation page?

Can I get this back from the IPN?

Answer (score 0):

Once they have completed the transaction it will show up in your HISTORY section. Next to the specific transaction click on "Details". This will provide you with all the information that was requested of them upon check out.

If you're using PayPal buttons make sure that the appropriate check boxes are checked when created the button to ask for the buyers address, otherwise it may not ask at all.

Comment: Can I get it back from the IPN so that I can use it on my site for order history?

Comment: I don't think the PayPal standard is setup to do that. You may have to upgrade to Website Payments Pro to get the result you want.